# What's the easiest way to match "foreground" or "foregroun" or "foregrou" ... or "f" using Regex?

Tags: regex

What's the easiest way to match "foreground" or "foregroun" or "foregrou" ... or "f" using Regex? I know I can use the below Regex to do it. However I want to know if there is any simpler ones.

```
^f|fo|for|fore|foreg|foregr|foregro|foregrou|foregroun|foreground$
```

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? Because this would be much easier with a simple text search.

Comment: No it haven't be a regex. You do it in text search will still need to compare each of them right?

Comment: No. No mention of programming language, but in pseudocode `if( indexof( x in "foreground" ) == 0 ) ...` where `indexof` returns the index of `x` in the string "foreground". If the result is 0 then `x` is a partial start of text "foreground".

Comment: @Juhana paranthesis mismatch there sir ;)

Comment: @Gusdor No there isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect; you need to limit the scope of the alternation by using a group (preferably non-capturing):

```
^(?:f|fo|for|fore|foreg|foregr|foregro|foregrou|foregroun|foreground)$
```

This is already as simple as it's going to get; an alternative (if you feel that the above regex violates the  DRY principle) would be

```
^(?:f(?:o(?:r(?:e(?:g(?:r(?:o(?:u(?:n(?:d)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)$
```

Comment: Don't you want those groups to be atomic or the quantifier to be possessive?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: No, why should they be?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: No. The groups are nested. So for example if the group that contains the `g` can't be matched, `round` won't even be attempted because they are in the same group.

Comment: I was going to post this answer but you beat me. Classic example of the readability / maintenance trade-off. I would do this in code tbh. c# -> `if(foregroud.StartsWith(input)){}`. you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks Tim for pointing out the error in my regex and providing the solution.